# How do I run `forever` from Crontab?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cron, forever

I am trying to schedule node server restart on OS reboot (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). I wrote:

```
crontab -u username -e
```

then I added following line:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start -c /usr/bin/node  /home/username/node/bin/www
```

I get the success message after saving or updating this file. There seems to be no effect on server reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wrap that into a bash script in the user's home directory's bin.

```
/home/username/bin/start_my_node_app.sh
```

Then in your crontab...

```
@reboot /home/username/bin/start_my_node_app.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Though according to this article, @reboot may not work for non-root users.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root

Comment: I tried `sudo crontab -u username -e` but it still doesn't work. I will try this solution and post back the results.

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: Sorry dude.  Consider writing a service which lives in /etc/init.d to kick it off, if it is a service, that's really where it belongs.  This might get you going in the right direction, good luck.  https://github.com/chovy/node-startup